# Lenovo screen resolution

Tags: resolution

I have a Lenovo Z51-70 80K6 and previously had a screen resolution of 1920x1080. After installing win10 recently it won't change from 1366x768.

I have tried re-installing windows again and updated both display drivers several times trying different ways. I have an identical one to compare it with and just can't seem to get it to work.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance